# CASE WHEN 2 results in 1 column have the same result in another column

Tags: sql, reporting-services, case

with the sample data below a collection_ref will carry 3 or 4 movements but the key 2 are the purchase and sale. The supply chain approved will be 1 once the movement is complete.
I want to CASE WHEN the movement is a Sale and Supply Chain Approved is 1 then a new column for all lines that have the same collection ref to show 'Completed' Else 'Outstanding'... any ideas?

Thanks in advance

[image: Sample Data]

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.bulk_type_code,
    a.bulk_number,
    a.supplier_contract_ref,
    a.supplier_consignment_ref,
    a.supplier_org_code,
    a.supplier_org_name,
    a.collection_ref,
    a.raw_weight_tons,
    a.financial_net_weight_tons,
    a.purchase_weight_tons,
    a.delivery_date,
    b.delivery_term_code,
    b.delivery_term_description,
    c.week_number
FROM    bi.bulk_subcontainer_pricing_group_summary a
LEFT JOIN bi.contracts b ON a.supplier_contract_number = b.contract_number 
OR a.purchaser_contract_number = b.contract_number
INNER JOIN bi.weeks c ON a.delivery_date BETWEEN c.start_date AND c.end_date
WHERE a.delivery_date BETWEEN @DFrom AND @DTo
AND a.bulk_type_code IN (@BulkType)
AND a.business_unit_code = 'OLLIMP'
AND a.pricing_type_group_code = @pricing_hidden
ORDER BY a.collection_ref
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could share the schema instead if writing out the column / key names.

It sounds like what you want is something like this

```
Select Case when Bulk_Type_Code = 'Sale' and Supply_Chain_Approved = 1 then 'Completed' 
when Bulk_Type_Code = 'Sale' and Supply_Chain_Approved = 0 then 'Outstanding'
else NULL end as CalculatedColumn
```

If the Bulk_Type_Code is not sale, then this column will be null.

Comment: Apologies by 'schema' are you referring to the SSRS Query?

Comment: What i'm looking to do is review all entries that have the same collection_ref and if the final entry is bulk_type_code = 'Sale' and supply_chain_approved = 1 then all lines with the same collection_ref are marked as completed. I then want to add a parameter to filter completed and outstanding collection_ref.

The end result in the report should show all collection_ref(s) that do not have a completed sale

Comment: When I said Schema I was just referring to the table definition/layout/columns, but in this case I don't think it's really required. 

Based on what you just said I don't think the case statement above is sufficient. I think you will need to have to use a MAX operator to determine if the collection_Ref has a sale where it is approved... Right now you will get 3 rows of null and one row of Completed/Outstanding

Comment: look at this SQLfiddle; I think it is doing what you want. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fc8606/1 -- Basically we wrap our case statement/query in an outer query so that we can aggregate the resultset

Comment: Thanks Aron, I'll give it a try
I have added the current schema from SSRS for ref